# Routing all Jersey REST requests through a method prior to execution

Tags: jersey, java-ee-7

What I would like to do is define a method at the root resource level that is called prior to any sub resources of that class. 
Looking through the API I see nothing like this.

Jersey 1.6

Comment: Jersey 1.6 is not EE 7.

Comment: are running in a cdi environment? This is where interceptors will  be most appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simplest way to do so is to have no-arg constructor of your Controller and call whichever function you want from there.

Comment: How would you annotate such a constructor? Can the @PerLookup be used to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need to annotate the constructor. Jersey runtime instantiates the constructor class with no-arg default constructor. If you define your own no-arg constructor that will be used by jersey.

Comment: I see this now in the lifecycle per request. Thanks!